# How to create X lists from X files that are in a list and assign X values at once to a dict keys from the created lists. [python]

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-requests

So i try to make X number of lists where X is the number of nargs provided in my program.
Example: `python program.py --payloads file1 file2 file3 file4`... up to 20 `nargs`.
This gives me a list of: `payloads_sets = [file1, file2, file3, file4]` (takes up to 20 files)

Now, here is the tricky part where i got stuck. I need to read from each file and iterate through each payload in the file simultaneously to set it in the request I'll make for every payload in the files.
TL;DR: There is a different payload set for each defined position (up to a
maximum of 20). The attack iterates through all payload sets simultaneously and places one payload into each defined position.

*For example:*

```
Payload_set_1 = [1, 2, 3,...]
Payload_set_2 = [a, b, c,...]
Payload_set_3 = [x, y, z,...]

data = {var_a: marked_position_1,
        var_b: marked_position_2,
        var_c: marked_position_3}
```

The desired sent requests:
for loop of something: send this:

```
data = {var_a: 1, var_b: 'a', var_c: 'x'}
data = {var_a: 2, var_b: 'b', var_c: 'y'}
data = {var_a: 3, var_b: 'c', var_c: 'z'}
```

Hope someone can clarify that for me or suggest another method to make it work.
**Long story short, I need to replicate what BurpSuite's Intruder Pitchfork attack does.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`zip`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) function with [destructuring](https://blog.tecladocode.com/destructuring-in-python/) in order to do this:

```py
var_names = ["var_a", "var_b", "var_c"]
values = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["x", "y", "z"]
]

# iterate through the values together
for cur_values in zip(*values):
    # match the values with their name
    named_values = zip(var_names, cur_values)
    # use the iterator of tuple constructor to make a dict
    value_dict = dict(named_values)
    print(value_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'var_a': 1, 'var_b': 'a', 'var_c': 'x'}
{'var_a': 2, 'var_b': 'b', 'var_c': 'y'}
{'var_a': 3, 'var_b': 'c', 'var_c': 'z'}
```

Comment: This looks cool, and will work for me, Thanks!.
Problem is: I need the program to create the list of lists of 'values'. 
The values will be created from reading through a list files [payload_file_1.txt, payload_file_2.txt, payload_file_3.txt, and so on...] (Depending on how much payload files the user gives in argument --payload) Once my program is able to do this, I can use your solution. If you can give me an answer it will be much appreciated.

Comment: Just loop through the files, read them, split on a newline, then append to the values array.